# Require 'bcrypt' failing on multiple operating systems, what am I missing?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, bcrypt

I'm trying to work in a simple authentication to replace the HTTP-Auth I've got in a small Sinatra application. bcrypt-ruby gem installs fine but `require 'bcrypt'` always throws an error: `no such file to load -- bcrypt`. I've confirmed the installation in my gem list, never had a similar error with another gem and while there's a fair amount of search results for bcrypt & not found errors, none of them offer a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does adding this before you `require 'bcrypt'` help?

```
require 'rubygems'
```

Comment: It did fix the issue. (I did have require 'rubygems' but the way I was requesting the file was skipping that portion). Thanks for your time.